# Is there a way for paragraph shading to recognize text wrap?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, text-wrap

I know how to manually change paragraph shading offset so it doesn't overlap with another text box that has text wrap turned on, but I want to know if there is a feature that will turn that on automatically. I have tried "clip to frame" in the shading options, but it doesn't work in this scenario.

Thanks!

[image: What is looks like when paragraph shading collides with another text box that has text wrap turned on]

[image: What it looks like after I manually adjusted the offset so it doesn't collide with the content of the other text box]

Comment: Is that callout text in a frame of its own? If so, set its background color to [Paper]. Background shading lives "inside" a text object and it doesn't have any further hidden properties. You also can't set text wrap to a single character or the line of an underlined text.

Comment: Another possibility (shall I say hack) is to add a white background to the anchored object so it covers the paragraph shading.

Answer (score 1):

Use paragraph rules instead. Those can be restrained to text.

Comment: Yes that works. However i feel that usinbg paragraph rules for content boxes is one of the biggest flaws in indesign.